# access to page run by node.js from outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, networking

I'm struggling with network problem.

I made simple test.js file like below inside virtual OS(Centos 7)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(7358);
```

and after command "node test.js", I checked it's working fine by using browser inside the virtual OS. (localhost:7358)

but the problem is when I try to access same page outside virtual OS.

(1) first, I set hosts file(I added the setting like below) of host OS(Window)

```
192.168.131.128       localhost
```

(2) and I checked the node is working fine.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :7358
tcp6       0      0 :::7358                 :::*                    LISTEN      9162/node
```

(3) and I stopped firewall inside virtual OS(Centos 7)

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

(4) and I checked ping is working from host OS to virtual OS

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>ping 192.168.131.128
```

but, the response from browser is "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
I have no idea what to do next... Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: How are you trying to access the guest from the host OS? http://192.168.131.128:7358/ or http://localhost:7358/ ? Redefining localhost in your hosts file seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @AuxTaco Hi there! Thank you for the comment, Actually I already tried with IP address(192.168.131.128:7358) not the domain "localhost". but didn't work as well. But thank you for giving me comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
Just delete the edit on hosts file. and rebooted.
It's working after then.